# Drawing an arrow doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, trigonometry

I am trying to draw an arrow in JavaFX. I did all the math and even accounted for radian stuff. For some reason, my arrow head isn't being drawn correctly. I almost think it has something to do with the domain/range of trig functions, but I can't be sure.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
package com.neonorb.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ArrowTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        double startx = 200;
        double starty = 100;
        double endx = 100;
        double endy = 300;

        double arrowAngle = Math.toRadians(45.0);
        double arrowLength = 10.0;

        double lineAngle = Math.atan((startx - endx) / (starty - endy));

        double x1 = Math.asin((arrowAngle + lineAngle) / arrowLength) + endx;
        double y1 = Math.acos((arrowAngle + lineAngle) / arrowLength) + endy;

        double x2 = Math.asin((arrowAngle - lineAngle) / arrowLength) + endx;
        double y2 = Math.acos((arrowAngle - lineAngle) / arrowLength) + endy;

        Group root = new Group();

        Line line = new Line(startx, starty, endx, endy);
        Line arrowHead1 = new Line(endx, endy, x1, y1);
        Line arrowHead2 = new Line(endx, endy, x2, y2);

        root.getChildren().addAll(line, arrowHead1, arrowHead2);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you compute x1 you add the result of arcsinus (ranging from about -1.57 to 1.57) to endx which is equal to 100. Same thing for y1, x2 and y2. That's why you get a small dark spot at the end of your line.

Comment: @StephaneM That is why I was thinking it had to do with the domain/range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>It's hard to "answer" this (non-question) with something more than...</sup>

...Your math is messed up in several ways:

- It should be `sin` and `cos` instead of `asin` and `acos`
- It should be `sin(x)*length`, and not `sin(x/length)`
- The `sin` and `cos` have been swapped
- The angle of the line should better be computed with `atan2` (the `atan` function that you used has some issues, obviously and particularly with `starty==endy`)
- The "offsets" should be added to the line angle - particularly, it should be `lineAngle - arrowAngle` instead of `arrowAngle - lineAngle`

The whole code, updated:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ArrowTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        double startx = 200;
        double starty = 100;
        double endx = 100;
        double endy = 300;

        double arrowAngle = Math.toRadians(45.0);
        double arrowLength = 10.0;

        double lineAngle = Math.atan2(starty - endy, startx - endx);

        double x1 = Math.cos(lineAngle + arrowAngle) * arrowLength + endx;
        double y1 = Math.sin(lineAngle + arrowAngle) * arrowLength + endy;

        double x2 = Math.cos(lineAngle - arrowAngle) * arrowLength + endx;
        double y2 = Math.sin(lineAngle - arrowAngle) * arrowLength + endy;

        Group root = new Group();

        Line line = new Line(startx, starty, endx, endy);
        Line arrowHead1 = new Line(endx, endy, x1, y1);
        Line arrowHead2 = new Line(endx, endy, x2, y2);

        root.getChildren().addAll(line, arrowHead1, arrowHead2);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```